# Jackson ignore customized ObjectMapper in API response of Quarkus app

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs, quarkus, objectmapper

I have the Qurakus app with REST API

```
@Path("/hello")
public class ExampleResource {

    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ObjectNode hello() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String str = "{\"var\": 0.000000009}";
        ObjectNode object = (ObjectNode) objectMapper.readTree(str);
        return object;
    }
}
```

With customized Jackson ObjectMapper as follow:

```
@Singleton
public class RegisterCustomModuleCustomizer implements ObjectMapperCustomizer {
    public void customize(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        mapper.enable(JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN);
    }
}
```

During response Jackson not invoke customized ObjectMapper, as a result the value returned in scientific notation.

If I use bellow POJO for response, Jackson invoke customized ObjectMapper as needed.

```
public class Entity {

    public Entity() {
    }

    public Entity(BigDecimal value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public BigDecimal value;

    public BigDecimal getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(BigDecimal value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Why Jackson ignore customized ObjectMapper?

Jackson need to invoke customized ObjectMapper.

Comment: What happens if you don't convert the string to `ObjectNode` but to `Map` instead, using `Map<?, ?> map = objectMapper.readValue(str, Map.class)`?

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json#jackson

Answer (score 0):

Implementations of `ObjectMapperCustomizer` are only applied to `ObjectMapper` classes that are managed by CDI (meaning they don't work on instances created with `new` at random parts of the code)

Comment: I mean the ObjectNode instance which return in the response must be intercepted by Jackson serialize to string before finally response. But during serialization custom object mapper not invoked.

Comment: I see that ObjectMapper that I used in API method misleading.  I edited API method, now there is no any new ObjectMapper:
@Path("/hello")
public class ExampleResource {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ObjectNode hello(ObjectNode object) {
        return object;
    }
}
If you sent POST request with json body as: {"value": 0.00000009} 

Response value forman will be in scientific notation 9.00E-08, custom global object mapper settings not used. 
But if we change ObjectNode to Entity object as I mentioned above response will have format as 0.00000009

Comment: The point still stands. You are doing `ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();` and there is no way Quarkus can apply the customizer to that `ObjectMapper`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the objectMapper managed by Quarkus, and not use your own one:

`@Inject ObjectMapper objectMapper;`